# Dictionary not iterating in order

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
masterdict = {'28': ['28057', '28095', '28033'], '04': ['04025'], '24': ['24023']}
```

I simply want to iterate through each item in order. It was doing so before, and now seems to start at '24', then '28' and '04'. Why would this be happening?

```
 for sFips, cFipsList in masterdict.iteritems():
    print sFips
    print cFipsList
```

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered in python 2

Comment: You want the `collections.OrderedDict` https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict , not just a regular dict.  For Python 3, dictonaries are ordered in insertion order, but in Python 2, that is not necessarily true.